# NerdTreeToggle always opens up two directory windows instead of one

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I'm using [Nerd-tree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) for vim. Whenever I use `:NERDTreeToggle` key, it opens up two directory windows instead of one, like so[image]

It's only when I type `:q`on one of the windows does it become like this
[image]
**How do I get it to only open one window on pressing the nerd-toggle key?**
Here's the [content of my .vimrc](https://gist.github.com/benawad/b768f5a5bbd92c8baabd363b7e79786f)(not created by me).

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759737/auto-open-nerdtree-in-vim) Putting this code in my .vimrc file helped solve the issue, now I only get one directory window instead of two.
`au VimEnter *  NERDTree`

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the lines from 80 to 94 and things will be fine.

As, it looks to me, the reason for this is because of opening NERDTreeFind , a new directory window is opened.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

on line 94 of your .vimrc replace `BufEnter` with `BufRead` like so

<s>`autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()`</s>

```
autocmd BufRead * call SyncTree()
```

With this line you don't need to have NERDTree always open when opening a file (which is what your current answer - `au VimEnter * NERDTree` does)